# Are these icons missing from the Bootstrap icons web font, or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, webfonts, bootstrap-icons

I'm using the web font for Bootstrap Icons, and most of my icons are working, but there are a few which are listed on the website that don't seem to be included in the web font. These include: bi-envelope-plus,bi-quote and bi-mortarboard. I'm using the CDN from          https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css and including them as follows:

```
<i class="bi bi-envelope-plus"></i>
```

Are some of the icons not included in the web font, or am I going crazy? The website provides the syntax to use them with the web font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest CDN from Bootstrap [site](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

Working [Example](https://codepen.io/musama125/pen/RwQjqxw)